# Tricking Scanner the input comes from the user

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, listener, stdin

I am writing a grading program that is going to grade assignments. My students have to use Scanner in one of their method.
My grader is a separate class that calls the students' methods. When I call the method with the Scanner, it prompts me to enter some input ( as it should ). I would like my grading class to be able to call the method and automatically input some predetermined string as if it was typed by the user without the program halting or pausing.

Is there any way how to do it in Java?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I know it might be confusing but this is actually very simple to implement, assuming that all your students declare Class and method same. So in your own class, just implement your scanner-processing method calling a method from your students class. :-)

Comment: Write your code so that you prompt for and take in user input in one method and then call _another_ method to act on that input.  The second method is just getting some data to work with; it doesn't know or care where that data came from.  So you can "feed" it either data that you obtained from the user or that you've conjured up from thin air.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply replace `System.in` with your own input stream, perhaps a file that contains the input you wish to feed to the student's class.

Assuming the student's class looks like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Student {
    public String prompt() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter some input:");
        return scanner.nextLine();
    }
}
```

You could "grade" it like this:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Grader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.setIn(new FileInputStream("replies.txt"));
        Student student = new Student();
        String reply = student.prompt();
        assert reply.equals("reply");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can have your students read in file input. You could tell all of your students the name of the input file, and when you run your student's code, you'll have the input file on your computer. The students can test their own code with their own test cases, and when they submit they alter their code to file input. You can still have them output standard output.